# Slope of a line given multiple points

Tags: r, regression, excel

I have data with a starting (y) value that sequentially increments/decrements as (x) time  measured in days passes. 
I found this link for creating a linear regression of the data 
http://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/regression.php

I would like to automate the slope calculation in excel. Does anyone have an idea of how to do it? I see the math formula at the bottom of the page

$$\frac{N\sum XY- \sum X\sum Y}{N\sum X^2-(\sum X)^2}$$

but i don't know how to translate it to an excel formula. The problem is mainly the $\sum XY$ and $\sum X^2$. The others are easy with the `count`, `sum` and `pow` function. 
My x coordinates and y coordinates are in rows such that `C1` is `x1` and `D1` is `x2`.

Comment: it is more common to have y be the dependent and x the independent (e.g., time) variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, note that your link [links to a worked example](http://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/learn-regression.php) that will probably help.

To implement the equation in Excel:

1. make a new column labeled "XY" in E
2. enter the number of rows in cell "F2" (this will be N)
3. label column F "X^2"
4. enter `=C2^2` into F2 to caclulate X^2, highlight F2:FN and hit `ctrl+D` to fill this equation down
5. enter the equation `=(G2*sum(E:E) - sum(C:C)*sum(D:D))/(G2*sum(F:F) - sum(C:C)^2)` into an empty cell. This will be your R^2
6. enter the equation `=slope(D:D, C:C)` into another empty cell, this should match your calculation.

Finished result is shown in an example [google doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ai_PDCcY5g2JdGNabGs0R0IyVzhrUFIxOVRoTXMzUUE#gid=0) that can be downloaded in [Excel format here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ai_PDCcY5g2JdGNabGs0R0IyVzhrUFIxOVRoTXMzUUE&output=xls).

Comment: thanks give me a moment to implement it and i will ask a question

Comment: your example shows x1 at a1 and x2 at a2 my x1 is at c1 and my x2 is at d2

Comment: i guess i have to create n new columns for it to work

Comment: @caseyr547 Sorry, that was the linked to the 'published' version; I have updated the link to the raw spreadsheet, or you could download an [excel version here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ai_PDCcY5g2JdGNabGs0R0IyVzhrUFIxOVRoTXMzUUE&output=xls)

Answer (score 8):

A solution with R and the example data posted by @David and instructions on accessing data from google spreadsheets from the [Revolutions blog](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/09/how-to-use-a-google-spreadsheet-as-data-in-r.html)

```
require(RCurl)
mycsv <- getURL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ai_PDCcY5g2JdGNabGs0R0IyVzhrUFIxOVRoTXMzUUE&single=true&gid=0&range=C1%3AD11&output=csv")
mydata <- read.csv(textConnection(mycsv))

x <- mydata$X
    y <- mydata$Y
n <- nrow(mydata)
xy <- x*y
m <- (n*sum(xy)-sum(x)*sum(y)) / (n*sum(x^2)-sum(x)^2)
m
```

Or, you could use R's built-in function

```
lm(y~x)
```

Comment: thanks but my data isnt in that format my x1 is at c1 and my x2 is at d1 the xs and ys are on separate rows rather than separate colomns.

Comment: then you can use `t(mydata)` to transpose the matrix, or do this in excel using `paste -> special -> transpose`

Answer (score 1):

Excel already contains a function called SLOPE. See this [official help site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/slope-HP005209264.aspx) for reference and an example.

Answer (score 1):

With your X values in column A, and Y values in column B (no column headers):

```
=( (COUNT(A:A)*(SUMPRODUCT(A:A,B:B)) - (SUM(A:A)*SUM(B:B))) )/ 
 ( (COUNT(A:A)*SUMPRODUCT(A:A,A:A)) - (SUM(A:A)^2) )
```

If you want column headers, replace all A:A and B:B entries with the proper location of your values.

I figured this formula out so I could use the slope function in PowerPivot, which does not have a SLOPE formula.