# Slope / regression slope value of a non-linear line

Tags: regression

[Slope of a line given multiple points](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29525/slope-of-a-line-given-multiple-points)

Hello, I came across a closed question, but what I really don't understand is the formula being used - what is this formula (any authoritative references)? From my understanding, if I had a list of multiple points not forming a straight line, I can still find the "slope" of the regression line? - I am confused because how do I know the slope of a non-linear line as it would vary at each point?

I am planning to use this as a way to calculate "relative change" between multiple values on a timeline.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=least+squares+formula.  It might be that your question is new, but that depends on what you mean by "not forming a straight line."  Could you explain?

Comment: What I was trying to explain (very poorly) was an example of three points that are not lying on a straight line - what would be the formula for 'slope' of this curved line? - in my head, there is nothing like that unless you take only a set of of two points on that line and find it's slope?

But the formula in that link claims that there is something that represents the 'slope' of the curved line? I will try to read up on the least squares formula as you have linked in the mean time.

Comment: That formula just calculates the slope of the best fit line through the points.  That is, from simple linear regression. E.g., like, [image](https://i0.wp.com/statisticsbyjim.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/flp_linear.gif)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you that clears up a lot. So it does not give one singular value of the slope but generates the equation of that 'best fit' line. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula in the presented link just calculates the slope of the best fit line through the points. That is, from simple linear regression. E.g., like, [Image of best fit straight line](https://i0.wp.com/statisticsbyjim.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/flp_linear.gif).

I'm not sure how you would want to approach your specific problem.

- In terms of an overall slope, fitting a simple linear model like this is one option.
- A nonparametric approach with a similar goal would be to use Sen slope. (There are different variants and names, with some combination of the names Kendall, Theil Sen, and Siegel).  The basic idea is to take the median of the slopes between each pair of points.
- It might serve you to break the data into "segments" and fit a line to each group.  That is, you might have results like from *x* = 0 to *x* = 5, the slope of the best fit line is 2; from *x* = 6 to *x* =  10, the slope of the best fit line is 4
- It might be the best idea to abandon the idea of a single "slope" and just fit an appropriate curved line,
- or a "wiggly" model like local regression.